# SilverStripe filter on one-to-many relations data using filter method is not working

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. In my project, I am filtering data using filter method in the relationship (one-to-many). But it is not working.

This is my code.

```
Order::get()->filter([ 'Items.Status' => "InStock" ]);
```

That does not work. It is returning all the records instead. How can I apply the filter on relation data instead?

Comment: Do you want to return the `Item` with ID 123, or do you want to get the `Order` which has the associated `Item` 123?

Comment: So you have a domain like this: (`Order` - `has_many` - `Items`), (`Item` - `has_one` - `Order`) and `Item` has a data field called `Status`, is this defined inside `$db=[..]`? or is it a relation to a `has_one` Status model? -> if so, then that's there the problem is.


The code in your example looks correct to me, and should work if the `Item` model has a `Status` field defined in its own table.